# Map Over the Keys/Values from an Option[Map]

Tags: scala

I am trying to extract they keys/values from an Option[Map].  What is the simplest way to iterate over the key/values contains in the Map, only if the Option actually has a Map?

Here is a simple example that highlights my problem.

```
val values = Option(Map("foo" -> 22, "bar" -> 23))
values map { case (key, value) => println(s"$key = $value") }
```

This fails to compile.

```
 <console>:12: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]
              values map { case (key, value) => println(s"$key = $value") }
                                ^
```

If the Map is not wrapped in an Option, then it works just fine.

```
val values = Map("foo" -> 22, "bar" -> 23)
values map { case (key, value) => println(s"$key = $value") }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another `map`, because the first `map` is for the `Option`, which means the your lambda is trying to match a single key-value pair, when it's really the full `Map` contained in the `Option`.

```
values.map(a => ???)
           ^ This is a Map[String, Int]
```

Syntactically, you want this:

```
values.map(_.map { case (key, value) => println(s"$key = $value") })
```

But this isn't really a `map` in it's true sense, it's more like a `foreach` since it only produces a side-effect.

```
values.foreach(_.foreach { case (key, value) => println(s"$key = $value") })
```

Or with a for-comprehension:

```
for {
    map <- values
    (key, value) <- map
} println(s"$key = $value")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getOrElse` to unwrap the Map.

```
val values = Option(Map("foo" -> 22, "bar" -> 23))
values getOrElse Map() foreach { case (key, value) => println(s"$key = $value") }
```